# Laravel logoutOtherDevices feature : After logging in it's redirecting to last taken url instead of home url

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.7

In my application, if logged in on one computer,  need to log out on others.
I'm using [Invalidating Sessions On Other Devices](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices)

to implement the feature.
It's working. But the issue is, after logging in interchangeably in multiple devices, instead of loading home url, it's going to last loaded page.

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{      

    $data = $request->all();
    if (Spark::usesTwoFactorAuth() && $user->uses_two_factor_auth) {
        return $this->redirectForTwoFactorAuth($request, $user);
    }

    Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->password);
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

is included in my LoginCOntroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `intended()` does. If you check the source,

```
/**
 * Create a new redirect response to the previously intended location.
 *
 * @param  string  $default
 * @param  int     $status
 * @param  array   $headers
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function intended($default = '/', $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
{
    $path = $this->session->pull('url.intended', $default);

    return $this->to($path, $status, $headers, $secure);
}
```

... you will see that it will try to pull the intended url from the session. If you don't what that, you could just remove it.

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{      

    $data = $request->all();
    if (Spark::usesTwoFactorAuth() && $user->uses_two_factor_auth) {
        return $this->redirectForTwoFactorAuth($request, $user);
    }

    Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->password);
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

You also need to make sure that you have a `$redirectTo` property in your LoginController that points to your homepage.

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```