# Laravel 8 Auth::logoutOtherDevices always redirect to login route

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I use Auth::logoutOtherDevices to make sure that 1 user only can use 1 device. So when he login from another devices and authenticated, the other device will logout and redirect to form login. I already redirect to form login to my route "auth.show", but it alwasy redirect to route "login" first which i dont have. then after i refresh it will redirect to route "auth.show". so the problem is it alwasy redirect to route login. i also tried to dd("tes") on the middleware and same result, alwasy redirect to route login, then show the "test". what is the problem ?

here my Authenticate middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('auth.show');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181644/laravel-logoutotherdevices-feature-after-logging-in-its-redirecting-to-last-t

Answer (score 0):

You need just to add a route with name called login to your routes like this
Route::get('login',[Controller::class,'yourMethod'])>name('login');
to refer to the login page in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding `->name('login')` after the login route.